# SET-ACL via powershell for computer object

Tags: powershell, active-directory, acl

i am trying to modify a permission to multiple computers in my domain so that they are allowed to authenticate cross domain.

My code is simple however i keep getting an error.

```
Function Add-ADGroupACL
{
    param([string]$Computername,[string]$Access)
    #Get a reference to the RootDSE of the current domain
    $rootdse = Get-ADRootDSE
    #Get a reference to the current domain
    $domain = Get-ADDomain
    #Create a hashtable to store the GUID value of each extended right in the forest
$extendedrightsmap = @{}
Get-ADObject -SearchBase ($rootdse.ConfigurationNamingContext) -LDAPFilter `
"(&(objectclass=controlAccessRight)(rightsguid=*))" -Properties displayName,rightsGuid | 
% {$extendedrightsmap[$_.displayName]=[System.GUID]$_.rightsGuid}

#Create a hashtable to store the GUID value of each schema class and attribute
$guidmap = @{}
Get-ADObject -SearchBase ($rootdse.SchemaNamingContext) -LDAPFilter `
"(schemaidguid=*)" -Properties lDAPDisplayName,schemaIDGUID | 
% {$guidmap[$_.lDAPDisplayName]=[System.GUID]$_.schemaIDGUID}

    #Get the computer  object for modification on
    $Computer = Get-ADComputer -Identity $Computername

    #get the SID of the group you wish to add to the computer.
    $GroupIdentity = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(Get-ADGroup -Identity $Access).SID

    $computersADPath = "AD:\" + $Computer.DistinguishedName
    $ComputerACL = Get-ACL $computersADPath

    #Create a new rule to add to the object
    $newAccessRule = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule(
        $GroupIdentity,"ExtendedRight",
        "Allow", 
        $extendedrightsmap["Allowed To Authenticate"],
        "None")

    $newAccessRule
    #Add the rule to the ACL
    $ComputerACL.AddAccessRule($newAccessRule)
    #Set Rules to the ACL
    Set-Acl -AclObject $ComputerACL -Path $computersADPath
}
```

I have posted the entire function to make it easy.
Simply call this as so

```
Add-ADGroupACL -Computername 'TestComputer' -Access 'TestGroup'
```

end here is the error message that i keep getting

> Set-Acl : This security ID may not be assigned as the owner of this object
>   At line:88 char:5
>   +     Set-Acl -AclObject $ComputerACL -Path $computersADPath
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=testComputer,OU=Co...C=subdomain,DC=domain:String) [Set-Acl], ADException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ADProvider:SetSecurityDescriptor:ADError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAclCommand

The Access Rule looks right. it shows this.

```
ActiveDirectoryRights : ExtendedRight 
InheritanceType       : None
ObjectType            : 68b1d179-0d15-4d4f-ab71-46152e79a7bc
InheritedObjectType   : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
ObjectFlags           : ObjectAceTypePresent 
AccessControlType     : Allow
IdentityReference     : S-1-5-21-2926237862-3770063950-2320700579-361721 
IsInherited       : False 
InheritanceFlags      : None 
PropagationFlags      : None
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who gets this problem, the here is the solution.

Basically, how Get-ACL and Set-ACL works is that it retrieves the entire ACL. you make edits to the ACL and then Set-ACL attempts to rewrite the entire ACL.
More Info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthz/access-control-entries

So basically you need to just create an ACE and add it to the ACL on the fly. this can best be done buy utilising DACLS

Code:

```
Function Add-ADGroupACEExtendedRight
{
    param(
        [string]$Computername = $(throw "Computer name must be specified"),
        [string]$Access = $(throw "User or group in which to give acces must be specifieds"),
        [string]$ExtendedRight = $(throw "Extended Right Property Name Required")
    )

    #Get the computer  object for modification on
    $Computer = Get-ADComputer -Identity $Computername

    #get the SID of the group you wish to add to the computer.
    $GroupIdentity = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(Get-ADGroup -Identity $Access).SID

    #Set Permissions
    dsacls $Computer.DistinguishedName /G $GroupIdentity":CA;"$ExtendedRight
}
```

Usage:

```
Add-ADGroupACEExtendedRight -Computername "TestAsset" -Access "GroupID" -ExtendedRight "Allowed To Authenticate"
```

you can add any extended right here.
more information on DACLS: https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-pt/library/cc787520%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396